# How to reference two different tables to one common table with one foreign key in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have three classes, Item, Armor and Weapon.

ITEM is the parent class, that has generic properties, the ARMOR and WEAPON are the specific ones that I want to link to the item class.

Here is the database schema:

[image: database-schema]

One item is either an armor or a weapon, when I query, I want all the properties belonging to item and to the specific class.

```
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Consumable { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
}

public class Armor
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ArmorClass { get; set; }
    public ArmorType ArmorType { get; set; }
    public bool Stealth { get; set; }
    public int Strength { get; set; }
}

public class Weapon
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Damage { get; set; }
    public WeaponType WeaponType { get; set; }
    public List<string> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

I'm having trouble on how to link those tables, what properties to write where and stuff like that.

The idea is to use EF Core.

Answer (score 1):

You are going for inheritance. There are two types in EF TPT, Table per Type (each type gets its own table and they share the primary key), and TPI Table per Inheritance ( the whole inheritance gets a single table and there is a column that discriminates the types). EF core only supports the second one. This means your database schema needs to change into having only one table for this feature.

Another thing you can do is switch to composition instead of inheritance. So a weapon and armor will be composed of an item and the extra properties.

Here is an article that can help you with the specifics:
https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/table-per-type-inheritance-support-part-1-code-first/

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION 1**
If you really need a separate `Item` table
You need `Item` reference in `Armor` and `Weapon` classes

```
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Consumable { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
    // Following reference properties will get the **Armor** or **Weapon** properties, but it allows an `Item` to be an `Armor` and a `Weapon` at the same time
    public Armor Armor { get; set; }
    public Weapon Weapon { get; set; }
}

public class Armor
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public string ArmorClass { get; set; }
    public ArmorType ArmorType { get; set; }
    public bool Stealth { get; set; }
    public int Strength { get; set; }
}

public class Weapon
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public int Damage { get; set; }
    public WeaponType WeaponType { get; set; }
    public List<string> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

This way when you query an `Armor` or a `Weapon` it will be composed of an `Item`
You can access all common properties from `Item` property, like `armorObject.Item.Name`

**OPTION 2**
From your example, it does not look like you actually need an `Item` table. If it is the case,

You can have two tables each for `Armor` and `Weapon`

```
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Consumable { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
}

public class Armor : Item
{
    public string ArmorClass { get; set; }
    public ArmorType ArmorType { get; set; }
    public bool Stealth { get; set; }
    public int Strength { get; set; }
}

public class Weapon : Item
{
    public int Damage { get; set; }
    public WeaponType WeaponType { get; set; }
    public List<string> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

This way when you query any `Armor` or `Weapon` you get all properties

**SUGGESTION**
The model you are trying to use restricts you to only two types of `Item`s
If your system has the possibility to have more types of items in the future or additional properties to your types of items, I suggest you should have the following tables

- Categories (records will be Armor and Weapon)
- Attributes (records will be Stealth, Strength, Damage, Type, etc.)
- CategoryAttributes (mapping of attributes to category)
- Items
- ItemCategoryAttributes (value for attributes)

Comment: But like this I can't query an Item and get the Armor or Weapon Properties, right?